# Getting JSONObject from doInBackround() of AsynchTask and passing to main class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, json

I am trying to use the json object outside of the Async task but my class doesn't recognize it.

How do I pass the JSONObject to the outside of the Async task?

The only thing I could find was trying to use `onProgressUpdate()` to pass the object but I tried implementing and the object would come up blank :(.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is my class:

```
public class NewHomepage extends Activity {

    public static String url = "http://www.alkouri.com/android/SQL.php?username=";
    public static String usernamefromlogin;
    public static TextView errorchecking; 
    public static JSONArray user = null;

    //JSON Node Names 
    public String TAG_USER = "users";
    public String TAG_FIRST = "first";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reshomepage);
        //get data from previous screen
          Intent intent = getIntent();
          getIntent().getExtras();

          //convert intent (intent) to string called "usernamefromlogin"     
         //error checking in log cat to see value of "usernamefromlogin"      
          usernamefromlogin = intent.getExtras().getString("username2"); 
           Log.d("log usernamefromlogin", usernamefromlogin);

          //take the string "url" and add string "usernamefromlogin" after it       
         //error checking in log cat to see value of url5
          String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);                           
            Log.d("log url5", url5);

            //start asynch task
         class PostTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {
                  super.onPreExecute();

               }//end PreExecute

               @Override
               protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //pass url from outside class to inside this class   
                String url5 = params[0];

                //Creating new JSON Parser
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url5);

                return null;

               }//end doInBackground

             protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                  super.onProgressUpdate(values);
              }//end onProgressUpdate

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               super.onPostExecute(result);

               }//end onPostExecute
               }//end Async task

        //execute the Async task
        new PostTask2().execute(url5);

    }//end oncreate

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing on back press
    }
 }//end class
```

Comment: What do you want to get from your `JSONObject` ? Post your json response.

Comment: Checkout my answer and try out accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put AsyncTask calss outside the onCreate method and call it from inside onCreate method.

P.S. **However, as in the comment, post your json response and tell us what you want to parse from the response. On top of that, you need to use HTTP or Rest Client to query the server and get response.**

**EDIT**

To know how you can make a request to server, go through this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html) or you may also go through this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).

Comment: According to my knowledge, I don't think we can define a whole class inside a method, can we?

Comment: Have you ever tried ? Its not necessary to write it outside `onCreate()` . You can write it inside onCreate().

Comment: No, I haven't but I will sure check that now! But I don't think that will be a good coding.

Comment: But your answer is not the solution at all.

Comment: Its should be posted as comment.

Comment: I have edited my answer focusing on the parts where the real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull your asynctask out of your onCreate method and insert it as a nested class in NewHomepage.

Now, you can return a JSONObject from doInBackground() as shown in the code below. Note the AsncTask.

This is nice to learn something (the hard way) about activity life-cycle and memory leaks (I'm serious, try it, just for practice sake). For a real application however i'd highly recommend a Rest client library like [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley).

```
    public class NewHomepage extends Activity {

        // ... your activity code


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            new PostTask2().execute(url5);
        }

        class PostTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();

                    }//end PreExecute

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        //pass url from outside class to inside this class
                        String url5 = params[0];

                        //Creating new JSON Parser
                        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                        // Getting JSON from URL
                        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url5);

                        return json;

                    }//end doInBackground

                    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    }//end onProgressUpdate

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                        // HERE, this is running on the main thread.
                        // You can do whatever you need to do with your JSONObject.
                        // Maybe call setData(result) but be careful, the user might have left this activty already!
                        // And the View might have been already destroyed, so watchout for null-pointer-exceptions
                    }//end onPostExecute
                }
    }
```

Comment: And why exactly not ? Assuming his JSONParser's getJSONFromUrl syncroniously gets json from an url and returns a JSONObject ?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the `JSONObject` in your `onPostExecute` as below:

```
  class PostTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

          ..............................

           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //pass url from outside class to inside this class   
            String url5 = params[0];

            //Creating new JSON Parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url5);

            return json;

           }//end doInBackground

         protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
              super.onProgressUpdate(values);
          }//end onProgressUpdate

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           }//end onPostExecute
           }//end Async task
```

Comment: How is this different from what i have posted ? And you return JSONObject from your doInBackground(), not onPostExecute. Which is exactly the same as in my answer.